# I want to actuate a motor based on a wav file, but it has too many samples per second

Tags: python, audio, robotics

I am trying to actuate a simple DC motor based on a wav file. At the moment I am using the "cat vs dogs sounds" from Kaggle.

One of the wav files in this DB looks like this:

[image]

These audio files are just a few seconds. The sample rate is 16KHz.

My first idea was to just actuate the motor based on the amplitude, but at 16KHz this doesn't make any sense. Also, the signal goes constantly from + to - (this is sort of ok because the motor can move in both directions), but from a human POV, what the motor does doesnt make any sense, because the movements are too rapid. I then tried to "decimate" the signal into a few points per second, but the signals seem to be badly destroyed.

DC motors are actuated using an Adafruit board, using Arduino, and then I have a Python script that interfaces with the Arduino through serial. I have this working fine, and I can make for example a loop from python that increases the speed every few seconds. My idea was to go forward or backwards based on the amplitude of the signal (if it is negative or positive), I am no expert on audio, so this might make no sense. I won't react to other sounds, only to the input wav files.

I don't really know what is the best way of transforming an audio signal of 16KHz into something that can be use to actuate a motor. At the moment I am using a DC motor, but the idea in the near future is to use leds instead, and change their intensity based on the audio signals

Comment: How do you want to actuate the motor? What do you want it to do? When should it go forward and when backward? What properties of the sound are you looking for? How should it react to other sounds?

Comment: Hi Johan, I will also edit the post.  The DC motors are actuated using an Adafruit board, using Arduino, and then I have a Python script that interfaces with the Arduino through serial. I have this working fine, and I can make for example a loop from python that increases the speed every few seconds. 

My idea was to go forward or backwards based on the amplitude of the signal (if it is negative or positive), I am no expert on audio, so this might make no sense.

I won't react to other sounds, only to the input wav files.

Comment: What would "a negative sound" mean? Sounds are waves (at certain frequencies) and as such they will go from negative to positive and back over and over.

Comment: @JohanL what I mean is that if you look the amplitude it goes from + to -. So If I try to input that directly into a DC motor, it just moves back and forth very fast, and not making sense.

Comment: Yes, but what does negative amplitude of a sound mean to you? You are looking at the waves, and the signal moves up and down around the zero. Whether or not that is the (instantanious) amplitude or not might be debatable, but it is none-the-less not a good control signal for your motor. How quickly it moves up and down depends on the pitch but that is typically in the KHz (or at least several 100 HZ) range.

Comment: @JohanL you are right, and my main question is how should I transform the signal in order to make it "readable" by the motor

Comment: First you have to know your objectives. What should make the motor go forward and what should make the motor go backward? And why? Just looking at the instantaneous value of a sound wave makes no sense.